# Insertion Sort Variation

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void print_array(int array[], int size)
{
    cout<< "insertion sort steps: ";
    int j;
    for (j=0; j<size;j++)
        cout <<" "<< array[j];
    cout << endl;
}

void insertion_sort(int a[], int n)
{

    int i;
       for(int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
          i = 0;
          while ((a[j] > a[i])) {
            i = i+1;
          }
          int m = a[j];
          for(int k = 0; k <= (j-i-1); k++) {
            a[j-k] = a[j-k-1];

          }
          a[i] = m;
          print_array(a,n);
       }
}

int main() {
    int array[6]= {3,2,4,5,1,6};
    insertion_sort(array,6);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to modify this the insertion sort that it uses a linear search technique that inserts the jth element in the correct place by first comparing it with the (j − 1)st element, then the (j − 2)th element if necessary, and so on.

So where it says `i = 0;` it should now be `i = j-1;`

My attempt:

```
void insertion_sort(int a[], int n)
{

    int i;
       for(int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
          i = j-1;
          while ((a[j] > a[i]) && (i > 0)) {
            i = i-1;
          }
          int m = a[j];
          for(int k = (j-i-1); k >= 0; k--) {
            a[j-k] = a[j-k-1];

          }
          a[i] = m;
          print_array(a,n);
       }
}
```

Here is the output

```
insertion sort steps:  2 3 4 5 1 6
insertion sort steps:  4 2 2 5 1 6
insertion sort steps:  5 4 4 4 1 6
insertion sort steps:  5 4 4 1 4 6
insertion sort steps:  6 5 5 5 5 5
```

The first step is works correct by the 2nd step is when it all starts to fail.

Comment: So what is your question? When you debug the program, what do you discover? The second iteration is only a dozen steps. Step through each line. Shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
          while ((a[j] > a[i]) && (i > 0)) {
            i = i-1;
          }
```

is wrong, because it causes insertion of `a[j]` at index `0` if `a[j]` were not to be moved. Change that to

```
          while (0 <= i && a[j] < a[i]) --i;
          ++i;
```

Also, the shifting loop is wrong and complicated - change it to

```
          int m = a[j];
          for (int k = j; k > i; k--) a[k] = a[k-1];
          a[i] = m;
```